# Extracting strings out of complex bracket system

Tags: perl

I have a string that look like this:

```
(((Q,(P,(O,(M,N)))),(B,A)),C)
```

And I want to group the letter inside the bracket like this:

```
1|MN
2|MNO
3|MNOP
4|MNOPQ
5|BA
6|MNOPQBA
7|MNOPQBAC
```

How can I do that? I'm new to programming and starting to write in Perl, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read the [ask] documentation. While your question is on-topic as it is about programming, it is asking for us to solve your problem entirely. It also looks a lot like a homework assignment. There's nothing wrong with homework, but you should think about it yourself. Cheating by letting someone else solve it will bite you later. Please take a moment to think about how you this could be done. Just think about an approach/algorithm and write that down if you can't do it in Perl. We appreciate effort around here. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a simple parser:

```
sub parse {
  my ($string_ref) = @_;

  # check if the remaining string is a (x,y) group
  if ($$string_ref =~ s/\A[(]//) {
    my $first = parse($string_ref);
    $$string_ref =~ s/\A[,]// or die "Expected a comma [,]";
    my $second = parse($string_ref);
    $$string_ref =~ s/\A[)]// or die "Expected a closing paren [)]";
    return [$first, $second];
  }
  # check if we have a simple string
  elsif ($$string_ref =~ s/\A([^,()]+)//) {
    return $1;
  }
  else {
    die "Expected [(] or [^,()]";
  }
}
```

This is a subroutine that calls itself for nested parts. It takes a reference to a string. To get the string inside that reference, we have to dereference it: `$$reference`. To create a reference, we use the `\` operator: `$reference = \$value`.

The `=~ s/.../.../` applies a substitution to a string. In the pattern, `\A` anchores at the beginning of the string, whereas `[...]` is a *character class*. Because the second part of our substitution is empty, the matching part at the beginning of the string is removed.

Now `my $str = "(((Q,(P,(O,(M,N)))),(B,A)),C)"; parse(\$str)` produces this data structure:

```
[[["Q", ["P", ["O", ["M", "N"]]]], ["B", "A"]], "C"]
```

The next problem is to flatten this data structure into your strings. Again we can write a recursive solution, as flattening the whole data structure is the same process as flattening just a part of this data structure.

```
sub flatten {
  my ($data) = @_;

  if (ref $data eq 'ARRAY') {
    my ($first, $second) = @$data;
    my ($first_str,  @first_others ) = flatten($first );
    my ($second_str, @second_others) = flatten($second);
    my $str = $first_str . $second_str;
    my @others = (@first_others, @second_others, $str);
    return $str, @others;
  }
  elsif (ref $data eq '') {
    return $data;
  }
  else {
    die "Unknown data type ", ref $data;
  }
}
```

The `ref` builtin returns the type of a reference. If the result is the empty string, then the value isn't a reference (in this case, it would be a plain string). The above code makes much use of list assignment: `($x, @y) = (1, 2, 3)` assigns the numbers so that `$x = 1` and `@y = (2, 3)`. This also works when there are fewer numbers – with `($x, @y) = (1)`, the `@y` would be empty. Note also that we return either a single value (when flattening a string) or multiple values (when flattening the contents of the parens).

Applied to that data structure, we get the list:

```
(
  "QPOMNBAC",
  "MN",
  "OMN",
  "POMN",
  "QPOMN",
  "BA",
  "QPOMNBA",
  "QPOMNBAC",
)
```

So how can we get the output you wanted?

```
use feature 'say';

my ($whole_string, @parts) = flatten(parse(\$str));

for my $i (0 .. $#parts) {
  say $i + 1, "|", $parts[$i];
}
```

Which produces

```
1|MN
2|OMN
3|POMN
4|QPOMN
5|BA
6|QPOMNBA
7|QPOMNBAC
```

The ordering inside the string is different than wanted – you seem to have sorted the parts in each parens almost alphabetically. For this, we would have to change something inside `flatten`. But without knowing how exactly you want to sort, this is impossible to do.

Comment: Neat explanation! Are you coming to the [GPW](http://act.yapc.eu/gpw2014/) this year?

Comment: @simbabque Thanks. I'm not quite sure if I'll go, but I'd certainly like to come. When would registration close?

Comment: Bitte schreib mir ne Mail an meine hannover.pm Addresse.

Comment: Thank you very much!! the ordering inside the string aren't important, really appreciated.

Comment: you are so awesome could you enplane more, when did the () get substituted with []?

Comment: @user3237143 The parens were not substituted. I wrote a parser that transforms a string into a data structure which we can use more easily in our program. The stuff with `[]` is a notation of this data structure, which happens to look very similar to the input which it represents. In Perl, you can look at a data structure with the `Data::Dumper` or `Data::Dump` modules (which I used here).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the the commas and provide the result as argument to the read function of any (mostly) lisp :)